# Find a group $G$ and $H\subseteq G$ that shows $(H\leq G$ iff $ab\in H)$ is not valid if $G$ is infinite.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The theorem says, let $G$ be a finite group with $H\subseteq G$, with $H\neq \varnothing$.

$H \leq G$ iff $ab \in H$ for all $a, b \in H.$

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Could you at least prove one of the two directions of the iff?

Comment: Is the question how does one prove the (finite) statement, or how to produce a counterexample when $G$ infinite?

Comment: @Travis it is provide a counter example

Comment: What is the simplest infinite group you know?

Comment: @Travis infinity to infinity

Comment: hint: $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be any group where there exists a $g \in G$ with order $g$ infinite. We have that $H = \{ g^k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not a subgroup. In particular, no elements of $H$ have inverses. However, for $g^n, g^m \in H$, you have $g^{n}g^m = g^{n+m} \in H$.

In general: If you have that $X$ is closed but not a subgroup, either the identity or inverses have to be missing!